# XOpenDisplay return display, but set errno to 11

Tags: c, x11, errno

I have a function,that open X11 display, do some stuff, and closes it. I use errno to catch errors throughout the code. After sometime debuffing I learned, that even though XOpenDisplay return the actual pointer (not NULL), errno is set to 11 in this function.

```
int
take_screenshot()    
{
  /* Get display */
  Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

  /* XOpenDisplay may set errno to 11
   * even though display is not NULL
   */
  if (!display)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening display: %s", strerror(errno));
    return 1;
  }
  XCloseDisplay(display);
  return 0;
}
```

It works fine, if add just `errno = 0` after `if statement`, but this looks like a bad idea. Also in man page it said that errno initial state is platform-dependent, but i check  and it's value is 0 before calling `XOpenDisplay`.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should only check `errno` if a function actually failed. Few functions are documented to set `errno` if they succeed. Treat the value of `errno` as *indeterminate* unless the documentation states otherwise.

Comment: [`errno` can be set to non-zero by effectively any function call](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.5p3): "The value of errno may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or not there is an error, provided the use of errno is not documented in the description of the function in this International Standard."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Some_programmer_dude metioned, I have mistread `errno`, which I used as an error indicator, so I should simply check docs and use `errno` only after `NULL` check